# How to retrieve Dataproc's jobId within a PySpark job

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I run several batch jobs and I would like to reference the jobId from dataproc to the saved output files.

That would allow to have all logs for arguments and output associated with the results. Downside remains: As executors in YARN past away, no logs for the single executor can be obtained anymore.

Answer (score 7):

The context of Google dataproc is passed into Spark jobs by using tags. Therefore all suitable information are present in the SparkConfig and can be accessed:

```
pyspark.SparkConf().get("spark.yarn.application.tags", "unknown")
pyspark.SparkConf().get("spark.yarn.tags", "unknown")
```

Output looks the following:

```
dataproc_job_3f4025a0-bce1-a254-9ddc-518a4d8b2f3d
```

That information can then be assigned to our export folder and output is saved with Dataproc reference:

```
df.select("*").write. \
    format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true') \
    .save(export_folder)
```